# CRITICAL_SECTION in C++/CLI

Tags: thread-safety, c++-cli

When coding in native C++, I'm using CRITICAL_SECTIONs frequently to create thread-safe code (or at least what I think to be thread-safe..). In C++/CLI, I guess it is also possible to use CRITICAL_SECTION? And is it wise to do so? If not, why? And what would be the alternatives?

Comment: Given that *C++/CLI* is basically *C++ for .NET*, I'm pretty sure *.NET* has a rich multithreading library whose functionality you could use instead.

Answer (score 2):

With their warnings about using unmanaged thread IDs because some implementations (like, IIRC, SQL Server) implement the stuff as fibers running on different threads, I'd avoid using unmanaged critical sections as well.

.Net code I've seen usually uses `System::Threading::Monitor::Enter()` and `Monitor::Exit()` for their critical section (conveniently wrapped by the `lock` keyword in C#). Otherwise, you can also use managed mutexes.

Comment: Thanks! So instead of using `EnterCriticalSection(this->cs);  ...  LeaveCriticalSection(this->cs);` I just write `Monitor::Enter(this); ..  Monitor::Exit(this);`?

Comment: Best practice is to lock a private `object` member, rather than `this`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Comment: @Medinoc I use `Monitor::Enter()` and `Monitor::Exit()`. But the link in your most recent comment points to some C#-only page. Just to make this very clear: In C++/CLI the "right" way is `Monitor::Enter()` and `Monitor::Exit()`?

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi That's how I understand it, at least (the C# `lock` statement is just a wrapper around these two methods).